# File Explorer hangs when viewing MS Office files with Details Pane open

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, microsoft-office

So, I have recently come across [this issue](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-files/file-explorer-crashing-when-trying-to-show-details/fcf6c000-d874-4e91-a25c-68c9e7db3fd0), where selecting any MS Office files (.doc, .docx, .xlsx, etc) while the Details Pane is open will cause the Windows Explorer process to hang. I have:

- restarted the PC
- repaired MS Office 2013 installation
- updated to the latest version of MS Office 2013 (v 15.0.5137.1000)

I am yet to re-install, as the program itself has no issues running.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue.
Seems to be a Google Drive Stream bug.
I've tried to remove all Google app & services and the problem is resolved.
But I cannot work without Drive Stream, so the only solution is to disable Details Pane.